# plotly pdf export changes font style

Tags: pdf, plotly

I want to save a figure that I created with plotly. In jupyter notebook, my plot has the right font. But when I save my figure to a pdf file, it changes the font. How can I keep the font?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(title="As you can see the font changes, how can I keep the font?",
                 font_family = "Latin Modern Roman")

fig.show()
pio.write_image(fig, "test.pdf")
```

Figure in jupyter notebook:

[image]

But the saved figure looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like there may not be an easy solution, as [this issue is being tracked as a bug on the plotly GitHub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4885).

But until the issue gets resolved, it seems that in order for the `png` exports to work properly, one should use fonts installed on the system (which may not be the same as those recognized by the browser/jupyter notebook, hence the discrepancy).

On Mac OS, what worked for me was looking at what fonts were available in the [Font Book](https://support.apple.com/guide/font-book/welcome/mac) and using those in the images to be exported to `png`.