# Plotly Python: Export image with different font styles

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, kaleido

### Problem Summary

I'm trying to export a plotly figure with multiple fonts / font stylings as a .png file.
Within the browser, the figure renders correctly. The y-axis has different font style that the rest of the figure.
Both fonts are installed on my system.
[image]

But if I try to export the image as a png-file, the different font styling for the y-axis seems to disappear.

[image]

### Minimum code example

`

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/master/titanic.csv")

fig = px.histogram(df, x="Age", color="Sex")

fig.update_layout(font_family="Arial")
fig.update_yaxes(tickfont_family="Arial Black")
fig.show()

fig.write_image("test_image.png")
```

`

My issue might be related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69412683/plotly-pdf-export-changes-font-style). But both fonts are installed on my machine.

Does anyone know how to include multiple fonts in a plotly figure export?

Comment: I ran your code in my environment and the font of the graph displayed is the same as the font of the saved image. My environment is plotly:5.11.0.

Comment: Hi @r-beginners,
thank you for your comment.
My issue is not that the font does not match, but that the font style (Arial for most of the layout except for Arial Black for the y-axis) are not displayed correctly when I export the figure as png.

Comment: And my environment is 
plotly: 5.11.0
kaleido: 0.2.1

Comment: I am using kaleido:0.1.0.post1 to avoid failures in saving images. I am getting my information from [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/static-image-export-hangs-using-kaleido/61519).

Comment: Thank you @r-beginners for pointing me in the right direction. Although the kaleido:0.1.0.post1 did not solve my problem, trying out different versions and ways of installing kaleido helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue has to do with kaleido:0.2.1 when installed via conda.

If kaleido:0.2.1 is installed via pip, the export of images with different font styles works just fine.